# Why can't update my linux kernel to the latest version 5.16?

Tags: linux-kernel, upgrade

Install the latest linux-image:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.16.0-0.bpo.3-amd64
```

List all my linux-image after installing.

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
linux-image-5.10.0-10-amd64         deinstall
linux-image-5.10.0-11-amd64         install
linux-image-5.10.0-12-amd64         deinstall
linux-image-5.10.0-13-amd64         install
linux-image-5.10.0-8-amd64          deinstall
linux-image-5.10.0-9-amd64          deinstall
linux-image-5.16.0-0.bpo.3-amd64        install
linux-image-amd64               deinstall
```

Reboot and check the kernel:

```
sudo uname -r
5.10.0-11-amd64
```

Why can't update my kernel to `5.16`?
Post more info on my os.
**grub info**

```
cat   /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub
#! /bin/sh
set -e

which update-grub >/dev/null 2>&1 || exit 0

if type systemd-detect-virt >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
   systemd-detect-virt --quiet --container; then
    exit 0
fi

set -- $DEB_MAINT_PARAMS
mode="${1#\'}"
mode="${mode%\'}"
case $0:$mode in
    # Only run on postinst configure and postrm remove, to avoid wasting
    # time by calling update-grub multiple times on upgrade and removal.
    # Also run if we have no DEB_MAINT_PARAMS, in order to work with old
    # kernel packages.
    */postinst.d/*:|*/postinst.d/*:configure|*/postrm.d/*:|*/postrm.d/*:remove)
    if [ -e /boot/grub/grub.cfg ]; then
        exec update-grub
    fi
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

**version**

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.92-2 (2022-02-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Pinned or not:**

```
sudo  grub-editenv list
nothing output
```

**update grub**

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot to enter into terminal:

```
uname -r
5.10.0-11-amd64
```

`5.16` related packages:

```
ls /boot
config-5.10.0-11-amd64       efi             initrd.img-5.10.0-13-amd64   System.map-5.10.0-13-amd64       vmlinuz-5.10.0-13-amd64
config-5.10.0-13-amd64       grub            initrd.img-5.16.0-0.bpo.3-amd64  System.map-5.16.0-0.bpo.3-amd64  vmlinuz-5.16.0-0.bpo.3-amd64
config-5.16.0-0.bpo.3-amd64  initrd.img-5.10.0-11-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-11-amd64   vmlinuz-5.10.0-11-amd64
```

And my [grub.cfg file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyzppbfy5o4tlp0/grub.cfg?dl=0) .
[image]
You can see that `initrd.img-5.16.0-0.bpo.3-amd64` is in the grub menu,why the os can't call it when booting?

Comment: Did you get any error messages, when you did the install?

Comment: Looks like you're using Debian 11 or some derivative of it. What are you using as a bootloader: the usual GRUB or something different? Normally a bootloader would default to using the newest kernel available, but your system isn't doing that. It's not using the 5.16. series backport kernel, nor even the newest standard kernel (`5.10.0-13-amd64`). Something must be wrong with the bootloader or its configuration scripts (`/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub` for GRUB).

Comment: `grub-editenv list` would also be useful to see if a version is pinned.

Comment: Nothing as output of `grub-editenv list` .